# I just installed the GMT package from synaptic, but none of the command can be found

Tags: software-installation, synaptic

I just downloaded the package GMT from synaptic however I cannot use any of the commands. For example, I got the package primarily for the 'minmax' command and when I type

```
minmax file.txt
```

I get

```
minmax: command not found
```

I do get the man page for minmax, however. Have I missed something during the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gmt` package seems to provide the file you want, but it's not in the standard `$PATH`.

To use it, you'll need to use the full path like so:

```
/usr/lib/gmt/bin/minmax file.txt
```

[reference](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=minmax&mode=exactfilename&suite=saucy&arch=any)

If you want to edit  your `$PATH`, you can  put this into `.profile` or somewhere else:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/gmt/bin/"
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid having to use the full path? We were taught to modify our .profile to ensure we don't have to type the full path for commands, but when I tried to I couldn't quite make it work.

Comment: @gbrooks: See my edit

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are supposed to prepend gmt commands with `GMT`:

```
GMT minmax file.txt
```